# How to read a large data from a database using WSO2 Dataservice?

Tags: java, sql, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

How to read millions of rows from a database using dataservice because it return for me an exception if i select more then 1100000 rows .

the exception below :

```
Trying to submit a response to an already closed connection : http-incoming-4
```

```
Select * from users;
```

should return all rows .

Answer (score 3):

Returning millions of data directly into any integration layer is not recommended. We need to leverage some other mechanisms such as cursors to return paged data so that we can keep integration layer focusing on integrations and not data transfer.

Assuming you are connecting to a MSSQL database, try to leverage SQL Cursors - https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-cursor/